# Stretched images in UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to add images to my UISegmentedControl but the image is always automatically stretched to fill the entire control (see picture). I'm currently setting the image by calling setImage:forSegmentAtIndex:. How can set the image so that it maintains its aspect ratio? This seems like it should be an easy thing to do but I haven't been able to figure it out.

[image: UISegmentedControl with stretched icon]

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I'm trying to get my image to stretch whereas it's just centered right now

Answer (score 3):

Use a @1x image that is small enough so that it does not need to be scaled at all, and the aspect ratio will not get messed up. Your @2x and @3x images can be larger, of course.

Comment: yup, works like a charm. If the image is small enough to fit in then it looks correct. If it is too large, it gets squeezed-in.

Answer (score 2):

When setting your image, use:

```
UIImage *myNewImage = [myOldImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)];
[segment setImage:myNewImage forSegmentAtIndex:i];
```

Where `top, left, bottom, and right` are the edges of the image you are willing to stretch. If you don't want any stretchable area, use `UIEdgeInsetsZero`.

Comment: I tried `UIEdgeInsetsZero` and now the image doesn't show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to set a margin around your image when you are setting the image :

```
yourSegmentedControl.setImage(yourImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10), resizingMode: .stretch), forSegmentAt: 0)
```

You can change the values of "top", "left", "bottom" and "right" as you want. This worked for me, I hope it will help!

Answer (score -1):

Very similar to dalton's answer, though I build my view in interface builder, so had to replace the images, something like this:

```
    self.codesDisplaySegment.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    for (int ii = 0 ; ii < self.codesDisplaySegment.numberOfSegments ; ++ii)
    {
        UIImage *img = [self.codesDisplaySegment imageForSegmentAtIndex: ii];
        img = [img resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        [self.codesDisplaySegment setImage: img forSegmentAtIndex: ii];
    }
```

Doing this solved my problem (which was as you describe.)

Comment: This resizes my image, but then my image becomes off center